# C bug - everything works but unused variable cannot be removed

Tags: c

No errors or warnings from debugger, but a memory sanitizer shows "uninitialized accesses", one for every line of output.

Output is fine, unless I change the size of or comment out an array that I ended up not even accessing (char ArrayThatINeverEvenUsed[10000]), the output is unexpected. The uninitialized access error appears in both correct/expected versions and in incorrect versions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("ID_List29.csv", "wb");

    // why does this program only work if there's an UNUSED array of size ~100000 or larger 
    char ArrayThatINeverEvenUsed[10000]; // why does removing zeros cause different outputs?

    int i , j, k , m;
    int sz = 0;
    char c, d, e, f;
    char tStr[8];
    tStr[4] = 0x7C; // pipe separator
    tStr[5] = 0x7C;
    tStr[6] = 0x0D;
    tStr[7] = 0x0A;

    for(i = 65; i < 91; i++)
    {
        c = i;
        tStr[0] = c;
        for(j = 65; j <91; j++)
        {
            d = j;
            tStr[1] = j;
            for(k = 65; k <91; k++)
            {
                e = k;
                tStr[2] = k;
                for(m = 65; m <91; m++)
                {
                    f = m;
                    tStr[3] = m;
                    fprintf(fptr, "%s", &tStr[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
puts("Exiting...");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output, and what is it when the array is removed?

Comment: If you want to remove the warning for unused variables, then use them, after you assign them. e.g. `tStr[1] = d;`  `tStr[2] = e;`  `tStr[3] = f;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null terminate your strings.

```
char tStr[9]
tStr[8]=0;
```

Your code works by accident otherwise.

The reason the code works has to do with the unused array growing the stack and putting `tStr` on the newly allocated page, thus initializing it to zeros, but there's something else here too. In any case, lots of undefined behavior to go around.

Comment: I'd also add a `fclose(fptr);`

Comment: @ChatterOne that's guaranteed for you when you return from main.

Comment: Yes, it's just about being explicit (but the code looks ugly enough that there are other things to change first).